# Spliting a std::array into a tuple of smaller sized std::array

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to split a `std::array<T, N>` into a tuple of smaller arrays, like `std::tuple<std::array<T, N1>, std::array<T, N2>, ...>` where `N1 + N2 + ... = N.`

```
namespace detail {
  // Summation of the given values
  template <class T>
  constexpr T sum(const T& x) { return x; }

  template <class T, class ...Args>
  constexpr auto sum(const T& x, Args&&... args)
  { return x + sum(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
}

template <class T, std::size_t... Ns>
constexpr
std::tuple<std::array<T, Ns>...>
f(const std::array<T, detail::sum(Ns...)>& x)
{
  // How do I implement this function?
}

int main()
{
  constexpr std::array<Foo, 5> arr = { ... };
  constexpr auto t = f<Foo, 2,3>(arr);
}
```

Actually I already implemented `f` but it's based on a loop which simply creates an empty array and copies the elements of the given array, but it doesn't work if T is not `default_constructible`.

I tried to utilize `std::integer_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`, but I think i'm totally lost with no clue.

Can anyone help me implement the function please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
template<class T,size_t...Is,size_t N>
std::array<T,sizeof...(Is)>
extract(std::array<T,N>const&,std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return {{arr[Is]...}};
}
```

now we just need to turn `{1,2,3}` into `{{0},{1,2},{3,4,5}}` roughly, with everything being C++ index sequences (so syntax).

Map `{3,4,0}` to `{0,1,2}` -- a count of indexes to subarrays.  Then map `{3,4,0}` x `1` to `{3,4,5,6}` and similar for the others.  That gives us the indexes inside the subarrays, which we feed to `extract` and bob is your uncle.

```
template<size_t n, size_t...counts>
constexpr auto
foo( std::index_sequence<counts...> )
->  offset_seq<
  sum_n<n>(counts...),
  std::make_index_sequence<get_n<n,counts...> >
>{ return {}; }
```

with various helpers to be written is the `{3,4,0}` x `1` to `{3,4,5,6}` portion, for example.